# target only added element in part of the animation chain

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to build an animation with jQuery but I am missing one simple step.
This is my actual code:

```
$('.wrapper').show('fast',function(){
    $(".bs-glyphicons-list-sub").append(appendable).fadeIn('slow').delay(500).removeClass('attivo');
});
```

`appendable` is a `li` element that is added to the `.bs-glyphicons-list-sub`. Appendable has the class `attivo` when it is created.
What I want to do make the li element to appear slowly with the class attivo and after half a second remove this class **from the addded li** only.
Actually it is trying to remove that class from the `.bs-glyphicons-list-sub`. How can I say: *remove it from the added li element only?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with this line

```
$(".bs-glyphicons-list-sub")
    .append(appendable)
    .fadeIn('slow')
    .delay(500)
    .removeClass('attivo');
```

is that it's `$(".bs-glyphicons-list-sub")` that's being chained through to the removeClass

The simplest solution would be access the item directly, eg:

```
$(".bs-glyphicons-list-sub")
    .append(appendable)
    .fadeIn('slow')
    .delay(500);
$(appendable).removeClass('attivo');
```

if `appendable` is already a jquery object, it's ok to "double-wrap" it, but not ideal, so would be just `appendable.removeClass("attivo")`

An alternative would be to use `.appendTo`, but you'll still need an extra navigation in there, eg:

```
appendable
    .appendTo(".bs-glyphicons-list-sub")
    .removeClass('attivo')
    .parent()
    .fadeIn('slow')
    .delay(500);
```

Note that `.removeClass()` is not affected by any animation and will occur immediately (so the `.delay(500)` in your original does nothing)

Comment: *The simplest solution would be find the attivo item after appending* yes but on the same ul there are other li elements that must keep the attivo class. that's why I am looking to target only this element.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about removeClass, didn't know about that! :-)

Comment: Given the animation doesn't affect the remove class, you can use .removeClass directly, updated based on your comment above.